# ListView with maybe more than 1 line

Tags: android, listview, layout

I want to create a list view which contain TextViews that are built from conceptually separate strings.

Some list items may have 1 line; others might have more than 1 line, for example:  Comment name = "alice", and comment text is a long string of text that must be wrapped to multiple lines:

```
alice commenttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt 

      ttttttttttttttt
```

but I want it to show:

```
alice commenttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt 

ttttttttttttttt
```

How to set the layout ?

Comment: Whoever gave the downvote:  Why downvote without explaining the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use two `TextView` in your layout, just use a single layout, built from your 2 source strings:

```
txt1.setText(comment.postedBy + " - " + comment.text);
```

It is not possible using the idiomatic Android ViewGroup layouts (e.g., RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, etc) to have the 2nd view ("commentttt..." in your example) both: a) "word-wrap" to a second line, and b) "float" around the first view ("alice" in your example).  The only way to achieve that type of flowing layout is to combine the two strings into a single `TextView`.  If you want varying styles as well, you can use something like [Html.fromHtml(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) to parse things like `"<b>This is bold</b> and this is not."`  There are other [Span types](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/CharacterStyle.html) that you can apply to text as needed.